# Failed to generate user instance in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using `.mdf` file for connectivity, when I select it it generates error:

> Failed to generate user instance in SQL Server due to failure in starting the process for the user instance

I have attached image to make it clear to you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1ae2.png

Can anyone answer my question.

Thank you!!

Comment: Check the Event Viewer on your SQL Server machine to see if you can find any additional info. What you've provided here isn't enough to diagnose the probelm

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps :

1. Stop all user instance processes of SQL Server running under your local account (open up task manager and look for `sqlsrv.exe` process and end it)
2. Delete all files in the `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS` folder
3. F5 again

The problem is known issue. SQL Server Express cannot create a user instance using the set of engine files in your local app data folder, deleting them should allow SQL Server to recreate them with the correct credentials for you to F5 successfully.

Comment: after modification an error occurred it says "A network related or instance specified error occurred while establishing a connection, a server was not found or is unable to access it"

Comment: you need to start sql server service again from configuration manager .

Comment: again it says "Failed to generate user instance in SQL Server due to failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed"

Comment: when i set user instance to false. it accepted .mdf file. am i doing right?

Comment: but after setting user instance to "false", it accepts .mdf file and says:An error occurred while connectivity to the database.The database might be unavailable.. An exception of type System.data.sqlclient.sqlexception occurred. The Error message is: "An attempt to attach auto-named database for file .mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened or it is located on UNC Share"